# Sending POST with cURL - Empty array

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to send a POST request with cURL, but unfortunately I'm only receiving an empty string.

cURL:

```
<?php
echo "ID: " . $_POST["id"]; // here ID is not empty

$fields = array(
    'id' => urlencode($_POST["id"]),
    'name' => urlencode($_POST["name"])
);

$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.de/remote.php");
curl_setopt ($connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, count($fields));
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
?>
```

Remote-Server:

```
<?php
   var_dump($_POST); // shows an empty array
?>
```

Comment: You're sending the number of fields, `count($fields)` in to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` instead of the actual fields, is that intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `count($fields)` and instead just use `$fields`

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Nowhere do you actually set the cURL option to send the fields