# Submitting XML and receiving a response

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have a little question that I am unsure about.  I have been given an IP with a port number and a username and password.  I am familiar with cURL but only receiving data (like from a webpage) and parsing that - no problem.  But now it would appear that I need to log on to a server and submit an XML file/string, and wait for a response.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to where to start with this that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST with cURL ([Sending POST with cURL - Empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264395/)).

I'd probably create a simple RESTful API to handle this. You can create a regular old, run-of-the-mill PHP script that will accept POST values, and give yourself a key/token pair. Then submit data to that PHP script, validating against the key/token pair.