# How to send and receive data to/from an API using CURL?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have to make an `API`. For this, I will receive the data from the mobile devices as `JSON` using POST. I have to work with this data and send the response back to the devices also as `JSON`.
But I don't know how to take the data that I will receive. I have tried to make some tests using `CURL` to see how can I take this data but the `$_POST` is always empty. Can you please tell me how to send the data as `JSON` format to the API using `CURL` and how can I receive this data so I can work with it and send it back as response?

These are my test files:

curl.php:

```
    //set POST variables
    $url = 'http://test.dev/test.php';
    $data = array(
        'fname' => 'Test',
        'lname' => 'TestL',
        'test' => array(
            'first' => 'TestFirst',
            'second' => 'TestSecond'
        )
    );

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data))
    );

    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $result;

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

test.php:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The response that I get is:

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: file_get_contents('php://') to get json value from request body

Comment: I have tried to use file_get_contents but I got the following errors:

    file_get_contents(): Invalid php:// URL specified in...
    file_get_contents(php://): failed to open stream: operation failed in...

Comment: file_get_contents('php://') will fetch you the json data submitted to your page...I think you missed single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the POST data as a URL query string or as an array, the problem is you post data in JSON format, but PHP does not parse JSON automatically, so the `$_POST` array is empty. If you want it, you need do the parsing yourself in the test.php:

```
$raw_post = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($raw_post, true);
print_r($data);
```

same questions: [1](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=123208&start=0&sid=e4765fb94fb809a8d8921590823c6bac) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264395/sending-post-with-curl-empty-array)