# How do I send data from one server to another WITHOUT html form?

Tags: php, curl, server

I am a beginner programmer, and I would like to send some data from my localhost xampp server to my cloud9 server. I am using curl to send the data,

```
> $post =  'url=testurl&message=testmessage'; $url =
> "https://server_address_to_send_data_to"; $curlSesh = curl_init();
> curl_setopt($curlSesh, CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($curlSesh,
> CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($curlSesh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
> $post); curl_setopt($curlSesh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> $response = curl_exec($curlSesh); curl_close($curlSesh); echo
> $response;
```

I have no idea how to receive this data on my server. The tutorials I have seen all show how to get the data if it was submitted in an html form, they all use the `$_POST['nameofvariable']`, but I do not have that variable as I did not use a form to insert the data, I want to simply send a string from one server to another.

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737861/how-to-send-and-receive-data-to-from-an-api-using-curl

Answer (score 0):

Since you are 'urlencoding' the body of your POST request, the target php script on your cloud9 server can simply process data as if they were sent from an HTML form. Therefore, you can do this on the remote server:

```
  <?php
    $url = $_POST["url"];
    $message = $_POST["message"]; 
     // do something 
      echo "something done!";
  ?>
```

In order to better figure out that,it would prove useful to look at what happens when you send a POST from an HTML form; you will probably see the same urlencoded string in the request body.

To monitor browser requests, responses, scripts, etc..., I usually leverage some developer-tailored browser tools (e.g, Firebug for Firefox).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136762/discussion-on-answer-by-notanumber-how-do-i-send-data-from-one-server-to-another).